# Add entries basing on found entry in Meteor publication

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I'd like to add new entries to Meteor publication basing on already found entry. I have sth like this:

```
Meteor.publish("thoughts", function (_id) {
    Thoughts
        .find({_id})
        .forEach(function(entry) {
            /* here I want to add new thoughts which should be also published
               basing on value of field 'classes' from 'entry' object */
        });
    this.ready();
});
```

How can I manage it?

//edit

Okay, once again: my first object looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : "XCauSwJ4Rm6Ap3yGr",
    "classes" : [ 
        "NHfWy7qaygkkt778b" //id of the second object (from the same collection)
    ],
    /* other fields */
}
```

The second one is like:

```
{
    "_id" : "NHfWy7qaygkkt778b",
    /* other fields */
}
```

I'd like to receive both of them (as pararell entries) knowing only `_id` of the first one.

Comment: You could check out something like https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.publish('thoughts',function(id){
  return Thoughts.find({_id:id},{fields:{'classes':1}});
})
```

subscribe the same on template by

```
 Template.tmplName.onCreated(function(){
     this.autorun(()=>{
        this.subscribe('thoughts',id); // id is the one you are giving to publication; 
     }) 

 })
```

Comment: First, your syntax is wrong, that's not proper JS object. Second, even after adding brackets there's still error - what exactly `fields` should do? And third, I feel I'm still not understood well - I've edited it again.

Comment: you needed classes only I thought, if you are not understanding probably you should give a bit more idea on what the output you are looking for.

A sample output code probably

Comment: I edited my post once again - I'd like to get two results, the first one should be the first object I pasted (with id `XCauSwJ4Rm6Ap3yGr`) and the second one - the second object (with id `NHfWy7qaygkkt778b`). I hope I am clear now...